# set calendar extender format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, date-format, calendarextender

Does anyone know if there is a way of specifying the Format of a calendar extender with a dynamic value from the aspx?
I tried this but it doesnt seem to set the format at all. Does anyone see anything wrong with it:

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbStartDate" runat="server" />
    <act:CalendarExtender ID="clndrStartDate" PopupPosition="Right" runat="server"
 Format='<%# DefaultDateFormat %>' TargetControlID="tbStartDate"></act:CalendarExtender>
```

and i have the DefaultDateFormat getter in a base page of the code beheind like this:

```
public static string DefaultDateFormat
    {
        get { return "dd/MM/yyyy"; }
    }
```

Any help would be appretiated.
Thank you

Comment: I can't make that work doing it in the markup, but changing the format in the code-behind is straightforward (and works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call DataBind Method on calendar extender instance.

```
clndrStartDate.DataBind();
```

This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean to say Format="<% =DefaultDateFormat%>" and you may not want DefaultDateFormat to be a static property.
You appear to be missing "" and = in your example. But I could be wrong.